# Jquery making post request to external site

Tags: jquery, xml, post, request, external

I need to make a post request to this site for example 
http://wwwinfo.mfcr.cz/cgi-bin/ares/darv_std.cgi?ico=27074358 
What Im supposed to do is parse the XML file from the site and put values into form fields.
I have found many ways how to do this locally but no luck on external page.
 Any help? Thanks a lot!

Comment: and whats i the problem?

Comment: please share your code what you have tried and where is the problem

Comment: Numerous reasons this might not work, CORS and  CSRF are two possibles. Need to provide more specifics about the actual requests by inspecting them in browser dev tools and use ajax error handlers also